# Finding finitely-generated $\mathbb{Z}[i]$-Modules that satisfy a certain condition

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

While preparing for an exam in Ring theory and Modules, I struggled to solve the following question: Find all finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}[i]$-Modules, $M$, that satisfy $\operatorname{Ann}_{\mathbb{Z}[i]}(M)=\langle{5}\rangle$.
So I know that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a P.I.D + $M$ is finitely generated $\implies$ $M$ can be represented as a direct sum of cyclic modules $\langle{a}\rangle = Ra$, where $R=\mathbb{Z}[i]$. But now I'm kinda stuck.

Comment: Have you tried the primary form of the structure theorem?

Comment: Well, I've tried your approach: By having a finitely generated module M over a P.I.D, I can write my module M as a decomposition $\bigoplus_{i} \frac{\mathbb{Z}[i]}{\langle{q_i}\rangle}$ where $\langle{q_i}\rangle$ are the primary ideals. Now, I want to remind us a theorem: R is a commutative ring and I $\lhd$ R, then I = $Ann_{R}({\frac{R}{I}})$. So a module could be $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[i]}{\langle{5^{a}}\rangle}$ ?            Note:  because we are dealing over a P.I.D, all primary ideals are powers of primary numbers $\langle{p^{\alpha}}\rangle$

Answer (score 1):

As I suggested in the comments, there is a solution that uses the primary form of the structure theorem. This is a sketch (you should be able to fill in the details):

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

$M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module, therefore we can write it as: $$M=R^t\oplus\bigoplus_{j=1}^{n}R/\langle p_i^{k_i}\rangle,$$
where the $p_i$ are primes in $R$.

We need to have $t=0$ (why?).

As you mentioned, in $R$, $(2+i)(2-i)$ is the prime decomposition of 5, so we can see that the only suitable $p_i-$s are $2\pm i$ (why?). So now our only candidates are: $$R/\langle (2+i)^k\rangle\oplus R/\langle (2-i)^r\rangle\cong R/\langle (2+i)^k(2-i)^r\rangle,$$ where $k,r\geq 0$ and the last equality is crt.

Now finish (i.e restrict the values $r,k$ can take and then verify these work) using the condition Ann$(M)\subset\langle 5\rangle$ (until now we've only used $5\in$Ann$M$).